# Nested JS views

Tags: sapui5

I have the following simple HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html;charset=UTF-8'/>
    <script src="resources/sap-ui-core.js"
            id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
            data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.commons, sap.ui.table, sap.ui.ux3"  
            data-sap-ui-theme= "sap_bluecrystal">
    </script>
    <script>
            sap.ui.localResources("zvhr_dashboard");
            var view = sap.ui.view({id:"idDashboard1", viewName:"zvhr_dashboard.Dashboard", type:sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.JS});
            view.placeAt("content");
    </script>
</head>
<body class="sapUiBody" role="application">
    <header class="header">Page Header</header>
    <div id="content" class="content">
        <div id="totalHoursChart" class="chartContainer"></div>
        <div id="totalCostChart" class="chartContainer"></div>
        <div id="totalCountChart" class="chartContainer"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

The containers **totalHoursChart**, **totalCostsChart**, **totalCountChart** are for line charts. Whenever the template is rendered because of the lines

```
var view = sap.ui.view({
    id:"idDashboard1",        
    viewName:"zvhr_dashboard.Dashboard", 
    type:sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.JS
});          
view.placeAt("content");
```

There is only one div created in **content** div and line charts that I draw and place at respective chart containers get overridden. I am unable to figure out how to do this nested views.

I have been unable to find one simple example showing how to do this.

Comment: Well, you're placing your view to the div `content`, effectively removing anything that was already inside that div.

Comment: However, I would advise to use just **one** div to put your content in; having multiple div's with multiple views is not the recommended way of building a UI5 application

Comment: But how would it support multiple views for example I want to draw three line charts on this page. How can that be achieved as each chart is a view in itself if I am not wrong

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate div to place your view in:

```
<div id="content" class="content">
    <div id="dashboardContainer"></div>
    <div id="totalHoursChart" class="chartContainer"></div>
    <div id="totalCostChart" class="chartContainer"></div>
    <div id="totalCountChart" class="chartContainer"></div>
</div>

view.placeAt("dashboardContainer");
```

Comment: If I follow your suggestion, would I need to make three different views for each chart?

Answer (score 0):

Well I was able to achieve what I needed and I guess it precisely does fulfill my requirement. I referred to [this](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#test-resources/sap/ui/layout/demokit/VerticalLayout.html) and understood that the whole page can have a layout and I can place multiple views inside that layout. 
The link I provided is of VerticalLayout but there are lot many options to pick from. Using it I was able to place three views(line charts in my case one below the other). The only thing I didnt like was that I had to give fixed width in pixels for every view that I placed inside layout, because when I gave width in percentages the views started shrinking after the page rendering was done.

So to follow the suggestion of @Qualiture I did it in one single div.

Comment: One of the (standard) benefits of UI5 is it's responsive nature, i.e. you should not need to specify fixed, absolute widths or heights. The `VerticalLayout` / `HorizontalLayout` indeed lack some flexibility here. I would advise looking at the `Grid` layout. It allows you to put UI elements on a 1/12th column layout (or a multitude of it) which allows for greatest responsive flexibility

Comment: @Qualiture something like bootstrap. I am Python Django developer actually just helping out a friend with his work and dipping my toes into SAP UI5.